# How to find nth occurrence in elements of an array, then replace digits after the nth occurrence with a zero in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, import

In Python, I am importing a .csv file, taking the 'IpAddress' column in the .csv, then putting the column into an array.
I would like to now edit each element in the array by replacing the digits in the last octet with a zero to make a new array.

**This is my current output:**

```
['10.232.4.174' '10.18.8.174' '10.18.8.195' '10.18.4.86' '10.18.4.90' '10.18.4.51' '10.18.4.87']
```

**My goal is to output:**

```
['10.232.4.0' '10.18.8.0' '10.18.8.0' '10.18.4.0' '10.18.4.0' '10.18.4.0' '10.18.4.0']
```

There are variations with a single string using the conditions:

`'.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-1]+["0"])` and
`ip= ip[:ip.rfind('.')+1] + '0'` but split and rfind() do not work this array.

How can I take the conditions for the single string, apply it to the whole array and output a new array?

**Here I'm importing the File and then putting it into and array:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\script\Result.csv')
data.head() 
newAddress =data['IpAddress'].values
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
input_ = ['10.232.4.174', '10.18.8.174','10.18.8.195','10.18.4.86','10.18.4.90','10.18.4.51','10.18.4.87']

data = pd.DataFrame({'IpAddress':input_})
sub_regex = re.compile('(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)(\d{1,3})')
data['IpAddress'].apply(lambda x: sub_regex.sub(r'\g<1>0', x))
```

Output:

```
0    10.232.4.0
1     10.18.8.0
2     10.18.8.0
3     10.18.4.0
4     10.18.4.0
5     10.18.4.0
6     10.18.4.0
Name: IpAddress, dtype: object
```

Here, the regular expression is separating your IP address into two groups, one with the first 3 numbers, and another one with the last one. Then, it uses a substitution command and places the first group, `\g<1>`, then places a zero. You can use the `apply` function to apply it to every row of your Series.